# leal and indirect addressing

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, att

Why is that replacing

```
movl    $84, 3(%rsi)
```

with

```
movl    $3, %ecx
leal    (%esi, %ecx, 1), %r11d
movl    $84, (%r11d)
```

results in `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and how can I solve it?

(I will be using `%ecx` as a counter later on to loop through the array)

---

As I understand it, `movl $84, 3(%rsi)` moves the literal value 84 (ASCII 'T') into `result[2]` (which works and correct, based on the printed output:    `24 = 02aTa`)

On the other hand,

```
movl    $3, %ecx
leal    (%esi, %ecx, 1), %r11d
movl    $84, (%r11d)
```

line 1 moves integer value 3 into `%ecx`
line 2 calculates `%esi + 1 * %ecx` = `%esi + %ecx` which is the same as `3(%esi)` (incorrect, as it does not work)
line 3 moves integer value 84 ('T') into the address above (which should be the same as `movl $84, 3(%rsi)`)

Replacing `%esi` with `%rsi` and so on (including using `leaq`, `movq`) in the non-working part, I get

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So my question is: **How can I achieve the effect of `movl $84, %ecx(%esi)`?**

---

Compile with `gcc main.c helper.s`

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void helper(unsigned int value, char * result);

int main() {
    char result[6];

    helper(24, result);
    printf("%5u = %s\n", 24, result);

    return 0;
}
```

**helper.s**

```
    .globl helper

helper:
    # 0
    movl    $48, 0(%rsi)
    # 2
    movl    $50, 1(%rsi)

    # a
    movl    $97, 2(%rsi)

#ifdef DEBUG
    # T
    movl    $84, 3(%rsi)
#ELSE
/*
    movl    $3, %ecx
    leal    (%esi, %ecx, 1), %r11d
    # T
    movl    $84, (%r11d)
*/
#ENDIF

    # a
    movl    $97, 4(%rsi)

    movl    $0x0000000000000000, 5(%rsi)

    ret
```

Replacing all `%rsi` with `%esi` (and all 64-bit registers with 32-bit registers), I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Why is this?

Comment: In 64-bit code - when dealing with pointers you should always use 64-bit registers, not 32-bit. I can only imagine that this is failing because `char result[6];` is an array on the stack, and pointers that will use stack addresses need a complete 64-bit value to properly represent them. You effectively cut off the upper 32-bits of the pointer by using just the 32-bit values when doing the `leal`. You want to use RCX, RSI and R11 not ESI, ECX, and R11D since all of these form the computation of or are intended to be pointers and used as such.

Comment: On a side note `movl    $3, %ecx` actually sets RCX to the value 3. If the target of an instruction is a 32-bit register then the processor automatically zero extends the value into the upper 32-bits of the 64-bit register.

Comment: `movl $84, 3(%rsi)` actually moves the 4-byte (32-bit) value 84 to address 3(%rsi). I think you intend to move just a byte with `movb $84, 3(%rsi)`. By moving 4 bytes at a time you end up clobbering other data in the array and the stack which likely leads to the stack smashing error.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I think you're right - using `movb` instead of  `movq` seems to work based on preliminary testing (will report back in a few days) - I completely forgot I was using a `char` array and `char`s are only a byte long

Comment: No, nothing is wrong. I was just pointing out that  `movl $3, %ecx` and `movq $3, %rcx` do the same thing. In fact the ECX version takes less space to encode the instruction as well.